# Convert binarystring to int, in C or C++

Tags: c, string, arduino, int, type-conversion

I have got a String filled up with 0 and 1 and would like to get an Integer out of it:
(platform in an Arduino UNO)

```
String bitString = ""; 
int Number;
int tmp;

bitString = "";
  for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {
    tmp= analogRead (A0);
    bitString +=  tmp % 2;
    delay(50);
  }
// now bitString contains for example "10100110" 
// Number = bitstring to int <-------------
// In the end I want that the variable Number contains the integer 166
```

Comment: @LaughDonor looks like this does not work on an Arduino

Comment: :/ I wasn't sure if all the libraries were available on that platform.

Comment: look at `long strtol (const char String_Input[], char **End_Pointer, int Base);`  i.e. int num = strtol(bitString, NULL, 2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a string of bits at all. Just do this:

```
  int n = 0;  // unsigned might be better here
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int bit = analogRead(A0) & 1;
    putchar('0' + bit);
    n = (n << 1) | bit;
    delay(50);
  }
  printf("\n%d\n", n);
```

Comment: looks like it does the job. how can I print out the binary string?

Comment: That depends. I'll edit the above to show one way.

Answer (score 1):

you can use strtol() function :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
char *a = "10100110";

int b = (int) strtol(a, NULL, 2);

printf("%d", b); //prints 166

return 0;
}
```